# Installation of tableau in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, tableau-api

I am trying to install Tableau in ubuntu 18.04 but getting errors

> dpkg: error processing archive tableau-server-2019-2-8_amd64.deb (--install):
>    new tableau-server-20192.20.0119.2115 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    tableau-server-2019-2-8_amd64.deb

Comment: most ubuntu versions come with an inbuilt software manager use it to install maybe some dependencies are missing.

Comment: Okay but how can I check for those dependencies, because all I get is that error

Comment: look for the dpkg log. the better option is to use the default software manager.

Answer (score 2):

**Tableau supports only**

CentOS 7

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7

Oracle Linux 7

Also for the ref:- https://community.tableau.com/thread/273257

Comment: I wanna install tableau for 18.04 coz just for tableau installing Os doesn't seem very reasonable

Comment: But as per there documentation they don't support 18.04 version.

Comment: @ArpitJain : https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/requ.htm The latest versions of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

As per their [installation document](https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/install_config_top.htm) you need to install it using `gdebi`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi -n tableau-server-2019-2-8_amd64.deb
```